# Probability - double entry

Tags: probability

I am studying a table of double entry X and Y, I made the most of the activities, related to covariance, correlation, but i can't make one of the exercises, which says: Calculate P(1 <= x <= 2, Y >= 1). I do not know how to do it.

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: The table is very large, and I do not know to relate the variables to perform the exercise, some formula or something like that, I need a light.

Comment: Are two tables of probabilities, X and Y

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the data. Basically, if the entries in the table are probabililties, then $P(1 \le X \le 2 , 1 \le Y)$ should be obtained by adding together all the entries that satisfy both conditions on $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I made two tables of probability X and Y, based on this i found the following data P(Y): P(0) = 1/3; P(1) = 1/3; P(2) = 1/3; P(X): P(0) = 1/3; P(1) = 5/18; P(2) = 7/18; I am still not succeeding.

Comment: You have given the [marginal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) for $X$ and $Y$. In order to calculate the probability you want, you will need the [joint distribution values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution). I.e. you will need $P(X=0, Y=0)$, $P(X=0, Y=1), \ldots$